# How to achive ListView with Search functionality and Search box should also scrollable?

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, android-custom-view

[image]

As Shown in image 1: I have listview with 2 items(half empty),and at the top i have one serch box I complete search functionality with custom adapter and Filterable but i want some other thing with this .they are

1. want to scroll listview with half empty(By Default it scrollable when Items more  than area)
2. Search box should also scroll with listview.(As shown in 2 picture.)
3. listview should be scroll up to last item (Here last item is Item2 should always shown )and item at top should highlighted with different color.

Comment: i found half solution from this link http://www.androidhub4you.com/2012/12/listview-into-scrollview-in-android.html but when i use this then setOnScrollListener not work .

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview can have only one direct child. So if you want to put more than one view in a single scrollview, you should put all the views you need to scroll, inside single container view `eg:-linear layout` and put those views in that.

Comment: How can scroll with less item?